# my sql query not giving any results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a sql query, but its not working out for me.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['gobtn'])) {

        mysql_select_db('sessions', $conn);
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

        if(!$conn) {
            die('Cannot connect to the database');
        } else {

            $sesid = $_POST['sesid'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `sessions`.`sesinfo` (`id`) VALUES ('$sesid');";
            $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

            if(!$retval){
                die('Cannot enetr into the database');
            } else {
                echo "Done bro!";
                mysql_close($conn);
            }

        }

    }
?>
```

**And the HTML Part:**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <h1 style="height: 60px; width: 500px; color: Black; font-family: Times New Roman; text-align: center; font-style: italic; font-style: bold; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 45%;">
            Enter any session ID: <input type="text" name="session_id" id="sesid">
            <input type="submit" value="GO" name="go_button" id="gobtn">    
        </h1>       
    </form>
```

I created db named as 'sessions'. It contains two tables:

id and text

I want to add the value of textbox input entered by user to the id table. But its not stopping on `die` command, and not even echoing out the last command. Any help would be appreciated alot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change this `if(isset($_POST['gobtn'])) { `  to `if(isset($_POST['session_id'])) {` You reference the form on its input name.Also first connect and then select the db

Comment: My bad. +1 for correcting me. Thanks. It works fine now.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Actually i'm kinda new to PHP, that's why i'm making these silly mistakes.

Comment: @AhmedDhanani You actually took the time to format your code well for us and describe the problem well. Which makes it fun to help people like you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
if(isset($_POST['go_button'])) {

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('sessions', $conn);

    $sesid = $_POST['sesid'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `sessions`.`sesinfo` (id) VALUES ('$sesid')";
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if(!$retval){
        die('Error!');
    } else {
        echo "Done bro!";
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
}
```

If your id is integer then your query will be->

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `sessions`.`sesinfo` (id) VALUES ($sesid)";
```